How do you change a SVG Image's Color in TMS WEB Core
I am adding an SVG image to a black background in TMS WEB Core and would like to change the color of the SVG image to White.
I have tried changing color in the properties but there is obviously no color function due to the web image control not being a visual component but rather only the image linked to it.
I am using TWebImageControl components for the SVG Images.
This is what mine looks like. I need the icons to be white instead of black:


The easiest way I have found to do this is by editing the path field to fill to another color of your choice in this case white. Here is an example:
procedure TMainForm.WebFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
SVGHome:String;
begin
  SVGHome:=  '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="IconSize"viewBox="0 0 576 512"><!--FA--><path **fill="#FFFFFF"** d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1h-32l.7 160.2c.2 35.5-28.5 64.3-64 64.3H128.1c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V287.6H32c-18 0-32-1' +
           '4-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L416 100.7V64c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32h32c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32V185l52.8 46.4c8 7 12 15 11 24zM248 192c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v80c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h' +
           '80c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V216c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H248z"/></svg>';
  HomeWIC.URL:= 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(SVGHome);
end;

The code written between asterisks(*) is not there on default and could be adjusted to any color


You can also set the fill color on the  tag and it should be inherited downwards in cases where there is more than one path.  Just make sure that all of your paths do not have a fill attribute (unless you want that color).
